# Using DBDeploy in Gradle with hibernate as the ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, gradle, dbdeploy

I am looking to use a versioned database migrations tool like DBdeploy in a java project which uses Hibernate as the ORM and uses Gradle as the build system. I am unable to lookup any documentation on running DBDeploy on Gradle. Also is there a Hibernate based migrations manager, which can understand schema changes by looking at changes in Hibernate classes/definitions?

Comment: Both the answers below are part answers to my question. Pity I cannot choose both as correct answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since dbdeploy has an Ant task, it should be straightforward to use from Gradle. See [Using Ant Tasks](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html) in the Gradle User Guide.

Answer (score 2):

> I am unable to lookup any documentation on running DBDeploy on Gradle.

Almost any build system can likely call either the ant task or the command-line interface for dbdeploy.

> Also is there a Hibernate based migrations manager, which can understand schema changes by looking at changes in Hibernate classes/definitions?

You might want to look at [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).  I haven't actually used it (I've used dbdeploy), but it has [hibernate integration](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/hibernate) that looks like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

this post shows how to use DBDeploy in Gradle:
http://blog.codeborne.com/2012/09/using-dbdeploy-in-gradle.html

Comment: While it's great to post links to useful information, please make sure you also include a brief summary of that information in case the linked page becomes inaccessible.